# Updating Web App code without reloading it

Tags: javascript, web-applications

Is there any way or possibility to update an apps code and have the client adopt it without reloading the app/website? I mean updating live application code, like adding or removing functionality.

The iPad asks for user permission every 24 hours for fullscreen webapps, for native apps it does not. Once you grant permission it will not ask again but if you reload the app, which you usually have to when you push an update, it will ask again if 24h passed.

We are installing iPads into Taxis and want to track connectivity around the city with geolocation data, but we can't do it reliably since the app would ask the guest for permission. We also would like to provide some location based features but wen can't do it because if one guest says "No", it will impact all next guests since the iPad only allows aksing twice and then you have to wait some time before you can ask for using Geolocation again,

Comment: Possible, but difficult and requires infrastructure

Comment: What do you mean by 'update an apps code'?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe him and his sysadmin don't get on...

Comment: You should not downvote something just because you don't see any need for you to do it. I have added an explanation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By update the code I presume you mean live code reload or changing the modules loaded on a page without changing it.

This would require you to have an infrastructure library that allows you to either reload or add modules of code to your applications. [ncore](https://github.com/raynos/ncore) allows this

Next you would need a communication channel from the server or some other remote end point to send new modules or module reload commands to the client browser.

The concept being that you have a websocket open and you send one of two commands

- add module : url
- reload module : name

The app in the browser would then either load and add that module from an url or reload that module.

This is basically remote control over the state of an application in a users browser.

Comment: you're helping this guy create an unmaintainable mess

Comment: Thanks, i am thinking about using Pusher for the websocket connection and maybe require.js for AMD.

Comment: @PabloFernandez it's not an unmaintainable mess, it's a really elegant concept to manipulate the state of an application as the union of a set of modules at run-time, remotely on any client

Comment: I will mark you answer as the solution now. Thanks you very much for your help.