# How to refresh the content when buttons are pressed?

Tags: flutter, widget, page-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I have a question about refreshing widgets when a button is pressed. As you can see the picture below, when I press on the button's (+) and (-) the text in between changes. However, the "Your GPA" and "Letter" does not change when I press on the button's (+) and (-). The only way it 'refreshes' the "Your GPA" and "Letter" is when i press on the container "+ New Subject," but then the next container doesn't refresh automatically. How can I make that possible? I put all the necessary files into this GitHub repository: https://github.com/Lauringschw/Help/tree/master

I would really appreciate your help. I am unsure how to solve this.

[image: This is what I have so far.]

Comment: Maybe this will help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067585/updating-web-app-code-without-reloading-it

Comment: Maybe you are missing a setState to update the UI. It would be better if you use streams, you can look into bloc patter or use change notifiers.